# Change save directory of Visual Studio 2008 project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a Visual Studio solution consisting of 2 projects. Unfortunately several files are spread out in different folders. I'd really like to just save everything to a new folder for simplicities sakes, but cannot find any option to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create folders and drag files around in the solution explorer tree.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in command to do this operation for you.  You will need to manually create a new folder and move all of the files into it via Solution Explorer.